# Create your own MD5 collisions

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, hash

I'm doing a presentation on MD5 collisions and I'd like to give people any idea how likely a collision is.

It would be good to have two blocks of text which hash to the same thing, and explain how many combinations of [a-zA-Z ] were needed before I hit a collision.

The obvious answer is hash every possible combination until hit two hashes the same.  So how would you go about coding this.  As a quick experiment I tried hashing every combination of 5 columns of [A-Z], storing this in a .net hashtable and catching the collision exception.  Two problems with this - the hashtable eventually times out, and I'm pretty sure I'm going to need A LOT more characters.

Obviously this data structure is too big to handle in memory, so now I'll have to get a database involved.  Also sounds like a good project to test out azure - a bit like [these guys](http://blogs.msdn.com/stevecla01/archive/2009/01/09/hooking-up-windows-azure-to-wikipedia.aspx).

Can anyone point me in the direction of an *efficient* way of doing this?

Comment: Check out [this paper](http://cryptography.hyperlink.cz/MD5_collisions.html) about hash function tunneling.

Comment: See here: http://cryptography.hyperlink.cz/MD5_collisions.html
It has links to some programs, e.g. this: http://cryptography.hyperlink.cz/2006/program_v1_pd.zip

Comment: Please mark one of the responses as the answer to your question? :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

These following two different 128 byte sequences hash to the same:

**MD5 Hash**: 79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4

The differences below are highlighted (bold). Sorry it's kind of hard to see.

```
d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab58712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89 
55ad340609f4b30283e488832571415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbdf280373c5b 
d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e2b487da03fd02396306d248cda0 
e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080a80d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f9652b6ff72a70
```

and

```
d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab50712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89 
55ad340609f4b30283e4888325f1415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbd7280373c5b 
d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e23487da03fd02396306d248cda0 
e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080280d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f965ab6ff72a70
```

The visualization of the collision/block1 (Source: [Links.Org](https://web.archive.org/web/20220812190633/https://www.links.org/?p=6))

[image]

The visualization of the collision/block2 (Source: [Links.Org](https://web.archive.org/web/20220812190633/https://www.links.org/?p=6))

[image]

Comment: Actual code for testing this (in [Python](http://python.net/~mwh/blog/nb.cgi/view/weblog/2004/8), [perl](http://yuweijun.blogspot.com/2008/10/md5.html)).

Comment: Actual code for testing this in JavaScript: https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/5525001

Comment: Got an even nicer example! It has two completely different images that are basically a collision: http://natmchugh.blogspot.de/2015/02/create-your-own-md5-collisions.html

Comment: @Iceland_jack Python link is not reachable!

Comment: For those confused like i was, both the red and green pixels represent diffs.  The black and white ones represent sames.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to do it with just text files, AFAIK. You can get *some* collisions, but having them also be from just [a-zA-Z] is not easy (yet).

On the other hand, if you just want two "meaningful"-looking files with the same hash, you can do it with something like, say, PostScript: have different binary blobs causing the collision, and use a conditional expression to display different output accordingly.

See e.g. [this problem](http://ipsc.ksp.sk/contests/ipsc2006/real/problems/h.html) (the H2 part) and [solution](http://ipsc.ksp.sk/contests/ipsc2006/real/solutions/h.html). For example, [this PS file](http://ipsc.ksp.sk/contests/ipsc2006/real/solutions/h1.ps) and [this one](http://ipsc.ksp.sk/contests/ipsc2006/real/solutions/h2.ps) have the same MD5sum but they are both well-formed PostScript files that have entirely different text in them when you open them.

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about how likely a straightforward collision is - one where there is no deliberate attempt to cause one - then you're going to be disappointed: You'd need to generate on average 2^64 plaintexts before you can expect to see a collision, and that's substantially more than you're going to be able to do in a reasonable (or really, even an _un_reasonable) time.

If you're looking to demonstrate the difficulty of deliberately crafting a collision, other answers have already demonstrated that. The extra constraint of requiring the strings to be entirely textual makes even those approaches largely impractical, though.

Comment: This is incorrect due to the birthday paradox: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox. In particular, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox#Cast_as_a_collision_problem

Comment: No - that's why I said 2^64, not 2^128. The birthday 'paradox' predicts a collision (on average) after 2^(numbits/2).

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [Hashcash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcash).  With an effective hash algorithm, like md5, the time to calculate a collision to exponential with the number of bits.  What Hashcash does is calculates partial collisions.  That is, a match of say the lower 16 bits of the hash.  To get the lower 16 bits to match, one would have to try hashing 2^15 different combinations on average.  If you know how long it takes to come up with a 16, 24, or 32 bit collision, then you can easily calculate out the time for higher numbers of bits.

Comment: Did you mean HashClash?

Answer (score -5):

The whole point of such hashes is that collisions are extremely unlikely.  You're not going to generate one by chance--your machine will almost certainly die of old age before you succeed.  The whole point of using a hash would go away if you could reasonably generate collisions!

Comment: MD5 collisions: http://th.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/People/lucks/HashCollisions/, http://www.doxpara.com/md5_someday.pdf, http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/rogue-ca/

Comment: Note that I said *BY CHANCE*.

Comment: Fair enough - when you say 'by chance' you mean 'brute force'?  so my question is really asking for something more efficient that brute forcing it.  or running the brute force combinations on a server farm like azure.

Comment: He wants to give people an impression of how likely they are--thus by chance, or brute force if you want to call it that, is the right metric.