# Hash collision H(x)=H(y) with x!=y, does that also mean H(x+z)=H(y+z) for random z?

Tags: hash, append, collision

Suppose H is some hash function (such as MD5 or SHA256 or whatever) and I have a collision for this hash: two different pieces of data x and y, that have the same hash.

In other words x≠y but H(x)=H(y).

Now if I concatenate some random data z, will H(x+z) be the same as H(y+z) ?

The idea is: x and y being a collision may imply that they happen to bring the H function in the same state (thus resulting in the same hash). From that point on, it doesn't matter what other data we append, their hashes will remain equal.

I tested the above for [this MD5 collision](http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/) and it seemed to work there. But I don't know if this is true in general?

Comment: Short version: It depends on the hashing function. See [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996495/hash-collision-and-appending-data?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This particular technique is called a [*length extension attack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack).  Whether or not a hash function is vulnerable obviously depends on the particular hash function.  Hash functions based on the [Merkle–Damgård construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction), such as MD5 and SHA-1, are vulnerable.  SHA-3 is not vulnerable, and [HMAC constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) are also not vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the has function. Since hash functions are not [homomorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) (that is, where: `f(x) = f(y)` implies `x = y`), it does not follow that `f(x + z)` and `f(y + z)` will map to the same item. Consider a counter example:

Given the hash function

```
f(x) = (x * 3) + 1 mod 6
```

then `f(2) = 1` and `f(6) = 1`. Let `z = 1`. Then:

```
f(2 + z) = 4 and f(6 + z) = 1
```

thus `f(2) = f(6)` but `f(2 + z) ≠ f(6 + z)`.

However, if the hash function were homomorphic, then by definition of homomorphism:

```
f(p + q) = f(p) + f(q)
```

and therefore:

```
f(x + z) = f(x) + f(z) 
f(y + z) = f(y) + f(z)
```

which but since `f(x) = f(y)` as you initially stated:

```
f(x) + f(z) = f(y) + f(z)
```

and so their hashes would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

(Please be indulgent, it's my first answer :D)
Not necessarily:

Consider the following data (as lists of numbers)

```
x = [8 0 4]
y = [8 1 0]
z = [5]
```

and the hashing function:

```
H([a b c]) = a + b*c
H([a b c d]) = H([b c d]) + H([a b c])
```

Then,  a collision for x and y occurs:

```
H(x) = H([8 0 4]) = 8 + 0*4 = 8
H(y) = H([8 1 0]) = 8 + 1*0 = 8
```

But when appending data, the hashes aren't equal:

```
H(z + x) = H([5 8 0 4]) = H([5 0 8]) + H([8 0 4]) = 5 + 8 = 13
H(z + y) = H([5 8 1 0]) = H([5 8 1]) + H([8 1 0]) = 13 + 8 = 21
```