# Collision generators or Datasets for hash collisions (like MD5, SHA-1 ...)

Tags: collision-detection, checksum, redundancy, hash-collision

I'd like to test 3rd party (including "closed source") tools (like synchronization, de-duplication...) behaves in presence of files with same size and digest checksum (popular ones CRC32, MD5,SHA-1 ... etc).
Some of those hashing methods have known vulnerabilities, so there exist ways of generating collisions.

Do you know about source of such datasets (other then brute-force try to create some :) ) or generators for creating such ?

To make clear about this : I am interested in sets of files with same checksum, file-size but different contents !

Comment: Dictionaries, logfiles, sourcecode, anything goes...

Comment: I don't ask for "anything". I ask for collisions, as they are hard to generate.

Comment: They are hard to generate because the functions are near-optimal and the key space is large enough. Remember the birhtday paradox: the chance of observing about *one* collision becomes about 1 once you have tested and hashed about sqrt(n) objects. For a 256 bit key that would be 2^^128 objects to insert. There are two possibilities: 1) reduce the keyspace (to say 32 bits) or 2) have a solid mathematical foundation. That's all you can do.

Comment: Exactly. But some of them, like md5, sha1 are broken. What you've said @wildplasser , are reasons why I am asking for dataset.

Comment: Are you testing tools that you've built, or 3rd-party programs?

Comment: 3rd part programs. My own tool have no such problems :). Thanks for pointing this out, I will put stress it out in question.

Answer (score 0):

As we know about weaknesses of md5 :

> In 2005, researchers were able to create pairs of PostScript
>   documents[24] and X.509 certificates[25] with the same hash. Later
>   that year, MD5's designer Ron Rivest wrote, "md5 and sha1 are both
>   clearly broken (in terms of collision-resistance)."[26]

source : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

we can find there (on wikipedia) and in following SO topic:

[Create your own MD5 collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933497/create-your-own-md5-collisions)

example pairs.

The question stays -> about nice datasets, with much more examples. (Or nice generators).