# MD5 collision edit two binaries keep same md5 without suffix

Tags: md5sum, hash-collision

Im working on some testing lab and have two binary files that have MD5 collision in the middle by having the combination of prefix + middle (different content) + suffix. However, i would like to make the two binaries keep the same MD5 hash, but different SHA256, by keeping the prefix and the difference bytes in the middle but not suffix at the end. So this differ from the .ps files example where you have identical values in the beginning, different in the middle and identical at the end. Will this be possible?

I tried editing both files with different tools and commands in Windows and linux dd, vim, hexeditor but all of these will lead to different md5sum.

Comment: You are basically asking `"how to create an md5 hash collision"`. You can google that phrase... There appears to be some [open source that can do that](https://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933497/create-your-own-md5-collisions